# Regex to Replace Wrapped Links with Unwrapped Links Not Working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, regex, google-chrome

I have this script

```
<script>
$(function($) {
  $('a[href]').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('href',
      $(this).attr('href')

      // these two lines make the script work for Firefox as well
      .replace(/.+?(?=(clk(n|g)\/https\/))/, '')
      .replace(/.+?(?=(clk(n|g)\/http\/))/, '')

      // this works for Chrome and Safari only
      .replace(/clk(n|g)\/https\//, 'https://')
      .replace(/clk(n|g)\/http\//, 'http://')
      .replace(/clk(n|g)\/tel\//, 'tel:')
      .replace(/clk(n|g)\/rel\//, ''));
  });
});
</script>
```

It's to unwrap instances of wrapped links, a feature I can't disable in a service I use.

In chrome, I load a page with the following, and it remains wrapped:

```
<a class="lp-element lp-pom-button" id="lp-pom-button-538" href="clkg/https/calendly.com/mydemo/my-demo" target="_blank"><span class="label">REQUEST A DEMO AND RELAX</span></a>
```

Any idea why it isn't working? It matches in RegEx debuggers.

Edit: What I mean by wrapped link is that the service changes my links like so:

```
https://calendly.com/mydemo/my-demo -> clkg/https/calendly.com/mydemo/my-demo
```

This directs clicks to the subdirectory of clkg/https/calendly.com/... now, and then redirects to https://calendly.com/... It's for the services conversion tracking, but it breaks all my native link decorators. UTM parameter persistence and Cross Domain Measurement no longer work, and the script was fixing that for awhile. Today it seems to have stopped working.

Comment: What is a wrapped link?

Comment: The version for FF doesn't do the same thing as the version for Chrome/Safari. The FF code removes everything before the wrapper, the Chrome/Safari version replaces it with a scheme prefix.

Comment: @Barmar It basically changes outbound link clicks to a subdirectory that redirects to the original link. The service I mention uses this for their conversion tracking. I updated my question.

Comment: `.+?` at the beginning of the regexp requires there to be at least 1 character before `clkg`. So it won't work if it's at the beginning.

Comment: I'm confused about the problem. The comment in the code says that it works for Chrome and Safari, but the text says it doesn't work. I tried `'clkg/https/calendly.com/mydemo/my-demo'.replace(/clk(n|g)\/https\//, 'https://')` in the Chrome console and it returned the desired replacement.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar. I'm not sure what to say, perhaps something else is wrong. Here's where I experience the failure: `https://www.axelgo.app/free-trial-offer/`. The script can be found in the source by searching for `replace`. Also, the evidence of it not working can be found by search for `go.axel.network`.

Comment: I'm going to try removing the `.+?`, Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: It's failing because jQuery isn't loaded. The error is `$ is not defined`. So the code never executes at all, it has nothing to do with the regex.

Comment: Okay, interesting. I'm not all that familiar with web development. Would it make more sense for me to adapt the <script> to not rely on jQuery, or should I inform my web-developer that jQuery isn't working on the page?

Comment: Probabvly better not to use jquery

Comment: There isn't really an answer to post, the question was based on a misunderstanding.

Comment: jQuery is a useful abstraction for the DOM, there is nothing wrong with it.